# Why MVar does not work with `par`?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing

Just curious. If I have 2 threads spawn using `forkIO`, communication between them can be done using `MVar`. I wonder if the same apply when using parallel Haskell's spark created using `par`. I understand `par` does not create an actual thread but just a pointer to some computation that can happen in parallel.

The following code compiles, `main` raises the following error: `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation`.

```
t1 a = putMVar a "Hi"
t2 a = do
  v <- takeMVar a
  print v

main1 = do
  a <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO (t1 a)
  forkIO (t2 a)

main = do
  a <- newEmptyMVar
  (t1 a) `par` (t2 a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wonder if the same apply when using parallel Haskell's spark created using par

No, this is not really possible. The `MVar` is an explicit, non-deterministic communication mechanism for use when manually controlling threads. `par` sparks are a much higher level abstraction, where the GHC runtime takes care of the communication for you.

When you attempt to spark an IO action, nothing happens, as sparked actions can be pure computations only.

Comment: thanks. just the part sparked actions can be pure only helps! :)

Comment: Moreover, even if you unsafePerformIO within the spark, sparks don't act as garbage collection roots, and may be discarded, so the check is well within its rights to find no potential writers ro the MVar.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a thread should run takeMVar first, then putMVar. That way, a thread blocks access to the MVar by the other threads.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Consider you have 2 threads, `t1` that fills into the `MVar` using `putMVar` and `t2` that reads from it using `takeMVar`. If `t1` runs first, it doesn't get blocked as the variable is empty, neither does `t2`. Now if `t2` runs first, it gets blocked, but is unblocked when `t1` puts into the variable. So it shouldn't really matter which one runs first. Whichever does and find itself blocked, it will just wait until it is unblocked.